# How to show content of custom fields in search results?

Tags: custom-field, loop, search

I was able to include the pages where there are custom fields in search results but I managed not to display the content when there is nothing in the content. Is there a way to include the content of custom fields in the loop?

Answer (score 1):

Something along the lines of [`get_post_custom()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom) or [`get_post_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) probably would suit your needs pretty well. You can feed either of them with `get_the_ID()` for the `$post_id`.